# Is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that has the in-betweenness property, somewhere dense?

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving, cantor-set

> Suppose $ X \subset \mathbb{R},\ $ with $\ \vert X\vert \geq 3, $ has
> the property that:
>
> $$ \forall\ x,y \in X\ \text{ with} \ x<y,\ \exists\ z\in X\ \text{ such
>  that } x<z<y.\qquad (\text{Property } 1)$$
>
> **Proposition**: $\ X\ $ is somewhere dense, that is: $\exists\ a,b, $ with $ a<b\ $ such that $ [a,b] \subset \overline{X}.  $

Note that Property $1$ does *not* say that $X$ is connected.

I was thinking something like, the Cantor set with endpoints removed could be a counter-example, but I'm not sure. And I also don't see how to proceed in a proof, for example a proof-by-contradiction. If we started assuming (by contradiction) that $X$ is nowhere dense, then this does not mean that every point of $X$ is an isolated point. So I am a bit stuck, although it is possible I am missing something simple.

Comment: What do you mean by $|X|\geq 3$ ? Do you mean cardinality?

Comment: $X$ has at least three elements.

Comment: Your notion of somewhere dense is not the standard one. Under how you've worded it here, $X = \mathbb{Q} $ is a counter-example.

Comment: What is the standard definition of somewhere dense then?

Comment: The standard one is that the closure of $X$ has nonempty interior

Comment: Question edited. Better now?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yep, forgot what dense meant. Deleted.

Comment: If you strike for minimalism in your axioms, then assuming $|X| \geq 2$ is actually sufficient, because the in-betweenness-property asserts the existence of a third point.

Comment: @red_trumpet yes I am aware of this. It's probably also true for $X = \emptyset\ $ and $\ \vert X \vert =1\ $ because of vacuous truth; However let's not waste time thinking about this because it is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the set of numbers which does not have $1$, in it’s ternary expansion and also has a unique ternary expansion, it clearly has the between-ness property but it is nowhere dense. In fact this is almost exactly the Cantor set.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson: I just got here and after looking at this answer I wondered whether the well-known (but maybe less elementary) examples of Cantor sets containing only irrational numbers would work, so I went back to double check exactly what the properties were (which I didn't fully remember) and realized that no Cantor set works.

Comment: This answer is still not obvious to me. This ternary stuff always confuses me and may require some thought. Can you explain/ give me an example of a real number that does not have a unique ternary representation?

Comment: $1/3$ is an example, they are exactly the numbers which are the edges of the cantor set.

Comment: In a base $b$ decimal system with $c =b-1$ then $0.\overline{cccccc}....=1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^m a_k\times b^{-k}; a_m \ne 0$ (i.e. a terminating decimal) may be written as $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} a_k b^{-k} + (a_m -1)\times b^{-k} + \sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} c\cdot b^{k}$.  Those the only numbers with ones without unique represtentations.

Comment: (Other than $0$ and $1$)

Comment: Ah OK. I think I don't even have to think about ternary stuff to get this counter-example. The way I think about it is the way Xander described: Like how in the construction of the Cantor set you remove closed intervals, here you remove open intervals of width $1/3.$ If you stop the "interval removal process" at a finite point, for example at the $5$'th iteration of the removal process, then you see that the only "problem" with this set answering the question is that you can choose two elements from the same interval. But letting this process tend to infinity gets rid of this only problem.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes, it’s the same thing, but thinking about it in tenerary makes it *very neat*.

Comment: I'm back, although it seems my most recent comment has been deleted (not by me). I agree the example works. The key idea is that between any pair of non-endpoint Cantor set points there exist complementary intervals (infinitely many, in fact), hence there exist non-endpoint points between these two non-endpoint points, namely all of those which are sufficiently close to an endpoint of any of those complementary intervals -- in fact there will be continuum many such points, since there are only countably many endpoint points and continuum many points **(continued)**

Comment: non-endpoint points of the Cantor set. This reminds me of an example in a 1902 paper by William H. Young ([link to paywalled copy](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s1-34.1.285) and [link to archive.org copy](https://archive.org/details/proceedingslond03socigoog/page/n308/mode/2up) and [link to google-books copy](https://books.google.com/books?id=J8-cAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA285#v=onepage&q&f=false)). The same set was used by Baire in 1899 for a different example (see 2nd to last paragraph in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/375187/15780)).

Comment: So would the set of numbers base $10$ (decimal) that only have zero's and ones in their decimal expansion also work? Is the set in Vivaan's answer similar?